# How to code min and max values for custom property to selected object?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, properties

The following script creates Custom Property "*TheNameOfTheSelectedObject*_MyFloat" to the selected object, but it doesn't have "min" and "max" values:

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.active_object
ob[ob.name + "_MyFloat"]=0.0
```

How set 'min' and 'max' values for the created property to selected object from script?

**The name of the created property needs to have object's name in it.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [bpy.types.Object.id_properties_ui](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.id_properties_ui) method that acts as a manager to change the custom properties settings on the fly.

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.active_object
prop_name = ob.name + "_MyFloat"
ob[prop_name] = 0.0
ob.id_properties_ensure()  # Make sure the manager is updated
property_manager = ob.id_properties_ui(prop_name)
property_manager.update(min=-10, max=10, soft_min=-5, soft_max=5)
```